# Is it possible to have different default values based on the value of provided arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

This is a very basic example of setting up `argparse`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--input_a", type=int, default=0,
                    help="first_input")
parser.add_argument("--input_b", type=int,
                    help="second_input")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The default value for an argument is the value that it takes if it's not provided explicitly when I call the script.

I want to modify the code above in order to have for `input_b` more than one default value. To be more clear, I want that the default value of `input_b` depends on the value of `input_a`. Is this feature covered by `argparse` library or should I make a workaround after the parsing?

---

#### Bonus Question

To further extend the question, could I set the default value of one argument on the base of more than one other argument?

Comment: Default values are put in the `args` Namespace at the start of parsing, and over written when relevant flag is parsed.  Interactions between arguments are possible with custom `Action` classes, but get messy.  It's better to do that kind of thing after parsing, when all arguments have been processed.

Comment: @hpaulj Have you any link that even remotely addresses this capability except for `argparse` documentation. I'm interested even if maybe is prone to mess.

Comment: You can read the `argparse.py` code for yourself.  Other SO questions have explored making parameters of argument depend on the values of others.  Most recently there have been several questions about changing the `required` attribute based on the presence or absence of another argument.

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't think about that but it's also an interesting possible feature.